# Extreme packet loss on wifi only when laptop is charging (plugged in)?

Tags: wireless, power-management

I have an MSI laptop with Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS Wayland installed, that I've used for years.

The last few weeks, I connected to some new guest wifi networks, one of which I've revisited periodically. I noticed a few days ago, starting after sleeping (suspending) my laptop, and then resuming at my main network location, that now whenever my laptop is plugged in and charging, there is significant packet loss (pings between 30%-75% packet loss) and trouble connecting to the known wifi network. This now happens at my main, protected wifi network also.

The dependent variable is whether the laptop is plugged in and charging. I've updated it (when on battery power) and have rebooted, shut it down, and resumed it multiple times and the issue has not gone away.
Sometimes if I boot up plugged in or already connect and then plug the laptop in, it will work for a minute or so then start dropping packets.
If I unplug the laptop, the network returns to "normal" functioning nearly immediately .

Here is an example ping result with this issue, when the laptop is plugged in:

```
$ ping 1.1.1.3
PING 1.1.1.3 (1.1.1.3) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 1.1.1.3: icmp_seq=1 ttl=56 time=19.2 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.3: icmp_seq=2 ttl=56 time=18.2 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.3: icmp_seq=3 ttl=56 time=18.0 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.3: icmp_seq=4 ttl=56 time=19.7 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.3: icmp_seq=5 ttl=56 time=18.3 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.3: icmp_seq=6 ttl=56 time=18.0 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.3: icmp_seq=7 ttl=56 time=18.6 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.3: icmp_seq=16 ttl=56 time=556 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.3: icmp_seq=17 ttl=56 time=18.3 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.3: icmp_seq=18 ttl=56 time=29.8 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.3: icmp_seq=19 ttl=56 time=24.9 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.3: icmp_seq=20 ttl=56 time=17.3 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.3: icmp_seq=21 ttl=56 time=14.5 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.3: icmp_seq=22 ttl=56 time=18.6 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.3: icmp_seq=23 ttl=56 time=15.3 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.3: icmp_seq=24 ttl=56 time=22.3 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.3: icmp_seq=25 ttl=56 time=18.2 ms

--- 1.1.1.3 ping statistics ---
32 packets transmitted, 17 received, 46.875% packet loss, time 31363ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 14.521/50.874/555.502/126.204 ms
```

This time it was actually more consistent than it usually is; usually the loss is more sparse and packets received or less grouped.

A perfect ping example when not plugged in / running on battery power:

```
 ping 1.1.1.3
PING 1.1.1.3 (1.1.1.3) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 1.1.1.3: icmp_seq=1 ttl=56 time=18.9 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.3: icmp_seq=2 ttl=56 time=18.0 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.3: icmp_seq=3 ttl=56 time=19.1 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.3: icmp_seq=4 ttl=56 time=19.9 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.3: icmp_seq=5 ttl=56 time=19.0 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.3: icmp_seq=6 ttl=56 time=20.4 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.3: icmp_seq=7 ttl=56 time=17.8 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.3: icmp_seq=8 ttl=56 time=18.7 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.3: icmp_seq=9 ttl=56 time=24.1 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.3: icmp_seq=10 ttl=56 time=19.8 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.3: icmp_seq=11 ttl=56 time=20.3 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.3: icmp_seq=12 ttl=56 time=24.4 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.3: icmp_seq=13 ttl=56 time=17.2 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.3: icmp_seq=14 ttl=56 time=17.0 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.3: icmp_seq=15 ttl=56 time=18.3 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.3: icmp_seq=16 ttl=56 time=15.1 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.3: icmp_seq=17 ttl=56 time=16.9 ms

--- 1.1.1.3 ping statistics ---
17 packets transmitted, 17 received, 0% packet loss, time 16022ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 15.093/19.112/24.382/2.300 ms
```

The laptop has had battery issues and sometimes issues resuming from an automatic suspend for some time, but this network issue is completely new.

Does anyone have an idea how I would go about fixing this, and what the issue might be ?

**Edit:**

Output of `sudo journalctl --follow` at time of issue, when running pings:

```
Jun 25 20:58:59 machine-name sudo[13406]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root(uid=0) by (uid=1000)

Jun 25 20:59:04 machine-name kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Microcode SW error detected. Restarting 0x0.
Jun 25 20:59:04 machine-name kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
Jun 25 20:59:04 machine-name kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Transport status: 0x0000004A, valid: 6
Jun 25 20:59:04 machine-name kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Loaded firmware version: 46.fae53a8b.0 9000-pu-b0-jf-b0-46.ucode
Jun 25 20:59:04 machine-name kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000071 | NMI_INTERRUPT_UMAC_FATAL    
Jun 25 20:59:04 machine-name kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00802AF4 | trm_hw_status0
Jun 25 20:59:04 machine-name kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | trm_hw_status1
Jun 25 20:59:04 machine-name kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x004895F6 | branchlink2
Jun 25 20:59:04 machine-name kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00479056 | interruptlink1
Jun 25 20:59:04 machine-name kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00006CA4 | interruptlink2
Jun 25 20:59:04 machine-name kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0001B3B6 | data1
Jun 25 20:59:04 machine-name kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00001000 | data2
Jun 25 20:59:04 machine-name kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xF0000008 | data3
Jun 25 20:59:04 machine-name kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x3DC0A3EF | beacon time
Jun 25 20:59:04 machine-name kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xF6AB6C12 | tsf low
Jun 25 20:59:04 machine-name kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000051 | tsf hi
Jun 25 20:59:04 machine-name kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | time gp1
Jun 25 20:59:04 machine-name kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x017FDF65 | time gp2
Jun 25 20:59:04 machine-name kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000001 | uCode revision type
Jun 25 20:59:04 machine-name kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000002E | uCode version major
Jun 25 20:59:04 machine-name kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xFAE53A8B | uCode version minor
Jun 25 20:59:04 machine-name kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000312 | hw version
Jun 25 20:59:04 machine-name kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00C89002 | board version
Jun 25 20:59:04 machine-name kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0B78001C | hcmd
Jun 25 20:59:04 machine-name kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x80022002 | isr0
Jun 25 20:59:04 machine-name kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | isr1
Jun 25 20:59:04 machine-name kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x08101802 | isr2
Jun 25 20:59:04 machine-name kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x4041FCCC | isr3
Jun 25 20:59:04 machine-name kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | isr4
Jun 25 20:59:04 machine-name kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0079019C | last cmd Id
Jun 25 20:59:04 machine-name kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0001B3B6 | wait_event
Jun 25 20:59:04 machine-name kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000080 | l2p_control
Jun 25 20:59:04 machine-name kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00002020 | l2p_duration
Jun 25 20:59:04 machine-name kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000003F | l2p_mhvalid
Jun 25 20:59:04 machine-name kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000080 | l2p_addr_match
Jun 25 20:59:04 machine-name kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000000D | lmpm_pmg_sel
Jun 25 20:59:04 machine-name kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x01030104 | timestamp
Jun 25 20:59:04 machine-name kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000828 | flow_handler
Jun 25 20:59:04 machine-name kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
Jun 25 20:59:04 machine-name kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Transport status: 0x0000004A, valid: 7
Jun 25 20:59:04 machine-name kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x2010071F | ADVANCED_SYSASSERT
Jun 25 20:59:04 machine-name kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | umac branchlink1
Jun 25 20:59:04 machine-name kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xC0088BBA | umac branchlink2
Jun 25 20:59:04 machine-name kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xC0084CC4 | umac interruptlink1
Jun 25 20:59:04 machine-name kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | umac interruptlink2
Jun 25 20:59:04 machine-name kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xDEADBEEF | umac data1
Jun 25 20:59:04 machine-name kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xDEADBEEF | umac data2
Jun 25 20:59:04 machine-name kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xDEADBEEF | umac data3
Jun 25 20:59:04 machine-name kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000002E | umac major
Jun 25 20:59:04 machine-name kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xFAE53A8B | umac minor
Jun 25 20:59:04 machine-name kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x017FDF4D | frame pointer
Jun 25 20:59:04 machine-name kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xC0886BFC | stack pointer
Jun 25 20:59:04 machine-name kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0079019C | last host cmd
Jun 25 20:59:04 machine-name kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | isr status reg
Jun 25 20:59:04 machine-name kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: IML/ROM dump:
Jun 25 20:59:04 machine-name kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | IML/ROM error/state
Jun 25 20:59:04 machine-name kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000003 | IML/ROM data1
Jun 25 20:59:04 machine-name kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Fseq Registers:
Jun 25 20:59:04 machine-name kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xE5D95D35 | FSEQ_ERROR_CODE
Jun 25 20:59:04 machine-name kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | FSEQ_TOP_INIT_VERSION
Jun 25 20:59:04 machine-name kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xAFB4E0FC | FSEQ_CNVIO_INIT_VERSION
Jun 25 20:59:04 machine-name kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000A384 | FSEQ_OTP_VERSION
Jun 25 20:59:04 machine-name kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x378D4177 | FSEQ_TOP_CONTENT_VERSION
Jun 25 20:59:04 machine-name kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x4344465A | FSEQ_ALIVE_TOKEN
Jun 25 20:59:04 machine-name kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x12D1C5D5 | FSEQ_CNVI_ID
Jun 25 20:59:04 machine-name kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xE08F78CC | FSEQ_CNVR_ID
Jun 25 20:59:04 machine-name kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x01000100 | CNVI_AUX_MISC_CHIP
Jun 25 20:59:04 machine-name kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x01300202 | CNVR_AUX_MISC_CHIP
Jun 25 20:59:04 machine-name kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000485B | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_DIG_DCDC_VTRIM
Jun 25 20:59:04 machine-name kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xA5A5A5A2 | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_ACTIVE_VDIG_MIRROR
Jun 25 20:59:04 machine-name kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Collecting data: ini trigger 4 fired (delay=0ms).
Jun 25 20:59:04 machine-name kernel: ieee80211 phy0: Hardware restart was requested
Jun 25 20:59:04 machine-name wpa_supplicant[1471]: wlo1: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=DRIVER type=WORLD
Jun 25 20:59:04 machine-name wpa_supplicant[1471]: wlo1: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=1 signal=-48 noise=9999 txrate=866700
Jun 25 20:59:17 machine-name kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Microcode SW error detected. Restarting 0x0.
Jun 25 20:59:17 machine-name kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
Jun 25 20:59:17 machine-name kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Transport status: 0x0000004A, valid: 6
Jun 25 20:59:17 machine-name kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Loaded firmware version: 46.fae53a8b.0 9000-pu-b0-jf-b0-46.ucode
Jun 25 20:59:17 machine-name kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000071 | NMI_INTERRUPT_UMAC_FATAL    
Jun 25 20:59:17 machine-name kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00002AF3 | trm_hw_status0
Jun 25 20:59:17 machine-name kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | trm_hw_status1
Jun 25 20:59:17 machine-name kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x004895F6 | branchlink2
Jun 25 20:59:17 machine-name kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00479056 | interruptlink1
Jun 25 20:59:17 machine-name kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00006CA4 | interruptlink2
Jun 25 20:59:17 machine-name kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0001B3B6 | data1
Jun 25 20:59:17 machine-name kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00001000 | data2
Jun 25 20:59:17 machine-name kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xF0000008 | data3
Jun 25 20:59:17 machine-name kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x1F013740 | beacon time
Jun 25 20:59:17 machine-name kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xF77788C2 | tsf low
Jun 25 20:59:17 machine-name kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000051 | tsf hi
Jun 25 20:59:17 machine-name kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | time gp1
Jun 25 20:59:17 machine-name kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00C279CC | time gp2
Jun 25 20:59:17 machine-name kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000001 | uCode revision type
Jun 25 20:59:17 machine-name kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000002E | uCode version major
Jun 25 20:59:17 machine-name kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xFAE53A8B | uCode version minor
Jun 25 20:59:17 machine-name kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000312 | hw version
Jun 25 20:59:17 machine-name kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00C89002 | board version
Jun 25 20:59:17 machine-name kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0B27001C | hcmd
Jun 25 20:59:17 machine-name kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xA6F22002 | isr0
Jun 25 20:59:17 machine-name kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | isr1
Jun 25 20:59:17 machine-name kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x08101802 | isr2
Jun 25 20:59:17 machine-name kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x4041FDCC | isr3
Jun 25 20:59:17 machine-name kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | isr4
Jun 25 20:59:17 machine-name kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0062019C | last cmd Id
Jun 25 20:59:17 machine-name kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0001B3B6 | wait_event
Jun 25 20:59:17 machine-name kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000080 | l2p_control
Jun 25 20:59:17 machine-name kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00001C20 | l2p_duration
Jun 25 20:59:17 machine-name kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000003F | l2p_mhvalid
Jun 25 20:59:17 machine-name kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x000000CE | l2p_addr_match
Jun 25 20:59:17 machine-name kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000000D | lmpm_pmg_sel
Jun 25 20:59:17 machine-name kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x01030104 | timestamp
Jun 25 20:59:17 machine-name kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000B038 | flow_handler
Jun 25 20:59:17 machine-name kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
Jun 25 20:59:17 machine-name kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Transport status: 0x0000004A, valid: 7
Jun 25 20:59:17 machine-name kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x2010071F | ADVANCED_SYSASSERT
Jun 25 20:59:17 machine-name kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | umac branchlink1
Jun 25 20:59:17 machine-name kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xC0088BBA | umac branchlink2
Jun 25 20:59:17 machine-name kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xC0084CC4 | umac interruptlink1
Jun 25 20:59:17 machine-name kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | umac interruptlink2
Jun 25 20:59:17 machine-name kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xDEADBEEF | umac data1
Jun 25 20:59:17 machine-name kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xDEADBEEF | umac data2
Jun 25 20:59:17 machine-name kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xDEADBEEF | umac data3
Jun 25 20:59:17 machine-name kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000002E | umac major
Jun 25 20:59:17 machine-name kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xFAE53A8B | umac minor
Jun 25 20:59:17 machine-name kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00C279B6 | frame pointer
Jun 25 20:59:17 machine-name kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xC0886BFC | stack pointer
Jun 25 20:59:17 machine-name kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0062019C | last host cmd
Jun 25 20:59:17 machine-name kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | isr status reg
Jun 25 20:59:17 machine-name kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: IML/ROM dump:
Jun 25 20:59:17 machine-name kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | IML/ROM error/state
Jun 25 20:59:17 machine-name kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000003 | IML/ROM data1
Jun 25 20:59:17 machine-name kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Fseq Registers:
Jun 25 20:59:17 machine-name kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xE5D95D35 | FSEQ_ERROR_CODE
Jun 25 20:59:17 machine-name kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | FSEQ_TOP_INIT_VERSION
Jun 25 20:59:17 machine-name kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xAFB4E0FC | FSEQ_CNVIO_INIT_VERSION
Jun 25 20:59:17 machine-name kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000A384 | FSEQ_OTP_VERSION
Jun 25 20:59:17 machine-name kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x378D4177 | FSEQ_TOP_CONTENT_VERSION
Jun 25 20:59:17 machine-name kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x4344465A | FSEQ_ALIVE_TOKEN
Jun 25 20:59:17 machine-name kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x12D1C5D5 | FSEQ_CNVI_ID
Jun 25 20:59:17 machine-name kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xE08F78CC | FSEQ_CNVR_ID
Jun 25 20:59:17 machine-name kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x01000100 | CNVI_AUX_MISC_CHIP
Jun 25 20:59:17 machine-name kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x01300202 | CNVR_AUX_MISC_CHIP
Jun 25 20:59:17 machine-name kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000485B | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_DIG_DCDC_VTRIM
Jun 25 20:59:17 machine-name kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xA5A5A5A2 | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_ACTIVE_VDIG_MIRROR
Jun 25 20:59:17 machine-name kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Collecting data: ini trigger 4 fired (delay=0ms).
Jun 25 20:59:17 machine-name kernel: ieee80211 phy0: Hardware restart was requested
Jun 25 20:59:18 machine-name wpa_supplicant[1471]: wlo1: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=DRIVER type=WORLD
Jun 25 20:59:18 machine-name wpa_supplicant[1471]: wlo1: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=1 signal=-49 noise=9999 txrate=866700
Jun 25 20:59:30 machine-name kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Microcode SW error detected. Restarting 0x0.
Jun 25 20:59:30 machine-name kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
Jun 25 20:59:30 machine-name kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Transport status: 0x0000004A, valid: 6
Jun 25 20:59:30 machine-name kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Loaded firmware version: 46.fae53a8b.0 9000-pu-b0-jf-b0-46.ucode
Jun 25 20:59:30 machine-name kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000071 | NMI_INTERRUPT_UMAC_FATAL    
Jun 25 20:59:30 machine-name kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00002EF4 | trm_hw_status0
Jun 25 20:59:30 machine-name kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | trm_hw_status1
Jun 25 20:59:30 machine-name kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x004895F6 | branchlink2
Jun 25 20:59:30 machine-name kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00479056 | interruptlink1
Jun 25 20:59:30 machine-name kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00006CA4 | interruptlink2
Jun 25 20:59:30 machine-name kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0001B3B6 | data1
Jun 25 20:59:30 machine-name kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00001000 | data2
Jun 25 20:59:30 machine-name kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xF0000008 | data3
Jun 25 20:59:30 machine-name kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x1EC01E68 | beacon time
Jun 25 20:59:30 machine-name kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xF842319D | tsf low
Jun 25 20:59:30 machine-name kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000051 | tsf hi
Jun 25 20:59:30 machine-name kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | time gp1
Jun 25 20:59:30 machine-name kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00C1097B | time gp2
Jun 25 20:59:30 machine-name kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000001 | uCode revision type
Jun 25 20:59:30 machine-name kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000002E | uCode version major
Jun 25 20:59:30 machine-name kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xFAE53A8B | uCode version minor
Jun 25 20:59:30 machine-name kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000312 | hw version
Jun 25 20:59:30 machine-name kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00C89002 | board version
Jun 25 20:59:30 machine-name kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0B8B001C | hcmd
Jun 25 20:59:30 machine-name kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x80022002 | isr0
Jun 25 20:59:30 machine-name kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | isr1
Jun 25 20:59:30 machine-name kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x08101802 | isr2
Jun 25 20:59:30 machine-name kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x4041FDCC | isr3
Jun 25 20:59:30 machine-name kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | isr4
Jun 25 20:59:30 machine-name kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0062019C | last cmd Id
Jun 25 20:59:30 machine-name kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0001B3B6 | wait_event
Jun 25 20:59:30 machine-name kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000080 | l2p_control
Jun 25 20:59:30 machine-name kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00002020 | l2p_duration
Jun 25 20:59:30 machine-name kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000003F | l2p_mhvalid
Jun 25 20:59:30 machine-name kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000080 | l2p_addr_match
Jun 25 20:59:30 machine-name kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000000D | lmpm_pmg_sel
Jun 25 20:59:30 machine-name kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x01030104 | timestamp
Jun 25 20:59:30 machine-name kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000A82C | flow_handler
Jun 25 20:59:30 machine-name kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
Jun 25 20:59:30 machine-name kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Transport status: 0x0000004A, valid: 7
Jun 25 20:59:30 machine-name kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x2010071F | ADVANCED_SYSASSERT
Jun 25 20:59:30 machine-name kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | umac branchlink1
Jun 25 20:59:30 machine-name kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xC0088BBA | umac branchlink2
Jun 25 20:59:30 machine-name kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xC0084CC4 | umac interruptlink1
Jun 25 20:59:30 machine-name kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | umac interruptlink2
Jun 25 20:59:30 machine-name kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xDEADBEEF | umac data1
Jun 25 20:59:30 machine-name kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xDEADBEEF | umac data2
Jun 25 20:59:30 machine-name kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xDEADBEEF | umac data3
Jun 25 20:59:30 machine-name kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000002E | umac major
Jun 25 20:59:30 machine-name kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xFAE53A8B | umac minor
Jun 25 20:59:30 machine-name kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00C10963 | frame pointer
Jun 25 20:59:30 machine-name kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xC0886BFC | stack pointer
Jun 25 20:59:30 machine-name kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0062019C | last host cmd
Jun 25 20:59:30 machine-name kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | isr status reg
Jun 25 20:59:30 machine-name kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: IML/ROM dump:
Jun 25 20:59:30 machine-name kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | IML/ROM error/state
Jun 25 20:59:30 machine-name kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000003 | IML/ROM data1
Jun 25 20:59:30 machine-name kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Fseq Registers:
Jun 25 20:59:30 machine-name kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xE5D95D35 | FSEQ_ERROR_CODE
Jun 25 20:59:30 machine-name kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | FSEQ_TOP_INIT_VERSION
Jun 25 20:59:30 machine-name kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xAFB4E0FC | FSEQ_CNVIO_INIT_VERSION
Jun 25 20:59:30 machine-name kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000A384 | FSEQ_OTP_VERSION
Jun 25 20:59:30 machine-name kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x378D4177 | FSEQ_TOP_CONTENT_VERSION
Jun 25 20:59:30 machine-name kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x4344465A | FSEQ_ALIVE_TOKEN
Jun 25 20:59:30 machine-name kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x12D1C5D5 | FSEQ_CNVI_ID
Jun 25 20:59:30 machine-name kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xE08F78CC | FSEQ_CNVR_ID
Jun 25 20:59:30 machine-name kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x01000100 | CNVI_AUX_MISC_CHIP
Jun 25 20:59:30 machine-name kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x01300202 | CNVR_AUX_MISC_CHIP
Jun 25 20:59:30 machine-name kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000485B | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_DIG_DCDC_VTRIM
Jun 25 20:59:30 machine-name kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xA5A5A5A2 | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_ACTIVE_VDIG_MIRROR
Jun 25 20:59:30 machine-name kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Collecting data: ini trigger 4 fired (delay=0ms).
Jun 25 20:59:30 machine-name kernel: ieee80211 phy0: Hardware restart was requested
Jun 25 20:59:31 machine-name wpa_supplicant[1471]: wlo1: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=DRIVER type=WORLD
Jun 25 20:59:31 machine-name wpa_supplicant[1471]: wlo1: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=1 signal=-49 noise=9999 txrate=866700
```

mtu is still 1500 during the issue, according to `ip link` output.